# Can we treat $\sim$ like =?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, notation

Saw this particular statement from my lectures

$\frac{(n-p)s^2}{\sigma^2} \sim  \chi^2$ then  $(n-p)s^2 \sim  \sigma^2 \chi^2$

My first question was what does $\sigma \chi^2$ even mean?

Secondly, why are we able to just multiplying both sides by $\sigma^2?$ Are we just treating $\sim $ like an $=$ sign? If so, why?

Comment: Could mean "drawn from a chi-squared distribution", indicating the left hand side is treated like a random variable. In that case, it depends on the properties of the distribution to scaling the random varaible.

Comment: In general if $$ X \sim P(x)$$ then $$cX \sim \frac{1}{c}P\left(\frac{x}{c}\right)$$

Comment: @benedict What do you mean by your second comment?

Comment: Thanks for the response Benedict. With the $X \sim P(x)$, if x is the parameter to our dist, then how would this fit in with the chi squared distribution and degrees of freedom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your confusion arises from what can be considered an abuse of notation in the equation you quote. If you treat $ \chi^2 $ as a random variable, then the relation makes sense because for any two random variables $X,Y$ on the same probability space $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P\right)$ if $X\sim Y$ then $f(X)\sim f(Y)$ for any Borel-measurable function $f$.  To see this, let $S \in \mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, that is, let $S$ be a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$ and observe that $$P(f(X)\in S) = P(X \in f^{-1}(S)) = P(Y \in f^{-1}(S)) = P(f(Y)\in S)$$ where the second equality follows from the fact that $X,Y$ are identically distributed. While I am being precise and using the language of measure theory, the basic idea is very simple and the measurability condition is usually satisfied by *most* functions. In particular, it is satisfied by $f(x) = \sigma x$

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense now! Thank you for the proof of the statement too!